# How to edit article via phpMyAdmin and MySQL?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 23 32"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at javaapplication4.JavaApplication4.main(JavaApplication4.java:28)
```

My example output is:

```
Enter positive integers, one number per line, ending with -1 
56    46    47    31    11
The sum of the numbers is 191
The average is 38.2
```

Code:

```
package javaapplication4;

import java.io.*;

public class JavaApplication4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(in);

        int num;
        int sum;
        int count;
        double average;

        System.out.println("Enter positive integers, one number per" +
        "line, ending with ..1");
        count = 0;
        sum = 0;
        num = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());

        while(num != -1){ sum = sum + num;
            count++;
            num = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the number is: " + sum);
        if(count !=0)
        average = sum / count;
        else
            average = 0;
        System.out.println("The average is: "+ average);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reconstruct your error by entering " 23 32" on a single line:

```
Enter positive integers, one number perline, ending with ..1
 23 32
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 23 32"
```

Then `Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());` tries to parse an Integer from " 23 32" what gives error as only digit characters are expected. Maybe try to using `Scanner.nextInt()` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) so that you don't need to care about whitespaces.

Also note that `average = sum / count` will give you wrong answer:

```
Enter positive integers, one number perline, ending with ..1
5
6
-1
The sum of the number is: 11
The average is: 5.0
```

as `sum` and `count` are both integers so integer division will be applied. In this case `11/2 = 5`. Therefore you should use `average = (double) sum / (double) count`.

And a final note. It's a good practice to initialize variables at declaration time:

```
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
```

Comment: i tried still got error the code given is this that need to output 
Enter positive integers, one number per line, ending with -1 
56    46    47    31    11
The sum of the numbers is 191
The average is 38.2

my code is this

Comment: System.out.println("Enter positive integers, one number per" +
                "line, ending with ..1");
        count = 0;
        sum = 0;
        num = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());
        
        while(num != -1)
        { sum = sum + num;
        count++;
        num = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the number is: " + sum);
        
        if(count !=0)
            average = sum / count;
        else
            average = 0;
        
        System.out.println("The average is: "+ average);

Comment: lol just got answer i will just put -1 to get the output thanks bro

Comment: thank you this is ok now forgot to comment back